# Add icons to comments editor in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: feature-request, comments, android-app, markdown

In the Android app, it would be helpful if there was a toolbar with the Markdown icons while writing comments, like the one present for when writing answers to questions.

Comment: I'd welcome it. Please note that comments support only a handful of basic markdown formatting, such as bold, italics, hyperlinks, etc. The rule may vary depending on the site.